# How to deploy files with extension .exe using Microsoft's Release Management 2013?

Tags: windows-installer, release-management, ms-release-management

I am facing issues in deploying files with extension **.exe** using **Microsoft's Release management 2013**.
I am able to install the same package by using **cmd** or directly by double clicking the installer.
I am also able to install package with extension **.msi** using the MSI Deployer tool in the Release Management 2013 tool.

Can someone please help me to resolve this problem.
What is the best way to completely understand the features offered by this Release Management tool
[image: Release Management error for deploying .exe files using MSI Deployer]

Answer (score 1):

I was using wrong methods of installing a .exe file using MSI Deployer.
Installation for .exe in powershell is different so i have used a different script to install .exe and created a custom action for the installation of the .exe which went successful.

I have used the options of creating my own custom action and tools (feature of the Microsoft's Release Management 2013).

used the below script:

**Start-Process -FilePath -ArgumentList -Wait -PassThru -NoNewWindow**